# Argument Error Using Prawn and Trying to Use an Instant Variable to Render an Image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, pdf, prawn

I am relatively new to programming and this is my first question so here we go:

I am getting the following error when trying to render an image with prawn:

```
ArgumentError in PropertiesController#show

/uploads/property/image/1/DSC_1749.JPG not found

Rails.root: /Users/Guest/Code/list
```

---

My code

```
class PropertyPdf < Prawn::Document

def initialize(property)
  super(top_margin: 70)
  @property = property
  building_heading
  spacing
  building_info
  spacing2
  offer
  spacing2
  offer2
end

def building_heading
  text "#{@property.building_name}", size: 30, style: :bold
  text "#{@property.comment}", size: 23, style: :italic
  building_photo = "#{@property.image_url}"
  image building_photo, height: 200, width: 200
end

end
```

Relevant Section in Show Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @property }
     format.pdf do
           pdf = PropertyPdf.new(@property)
           send_data pdf.render, type: "application/pdf",
                                 disposition: "inline"
     end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the file system *path* instead of the *url*. I assume you're using a file upload gem like CarrierWave or Paperclip. Try

```
building_photo = @property.image_path
```

or

```
building_photo = @property.image.path
```

Comment: I am using Paperclip and the second example worked for me as well.  I wish I could give you more than one up vote.  Thanks!